# Auto log off after 5 minutes except for one user windows server 2022

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2022

I have a single tower that has windows server 2022 on it. Everyone RDP's into that with different users to access the necessary software. After 5 minutes of inactivity the user should be logged out with the exception of one user sitting in the control room where that should be running all day. My original solution was to go to local group policy editor and go to computer configuration -> windows settings -> security settings -> local policies -> security options -> interactive logon: machine inactivity limit -> 300 seconds
However, this won't exclude the one user I need. I also tried going into computer management and limiting all the user's idle sessions except for that one's to 5 minutes, but they stay logged on well past 5 minutes of inactivity anyway. Is there a better way to do this or a way to add an exception to local group policy? Thank you

Comment: You could do this with powershell and a scheduled task, but it wouldn't be exactly 300 seconds. You could run a script every minute or so, so it would be between 301 and 360 seconds

Comment: That would be fine as well, do you have an example or link to an article that does this? And this would allow user exclusion?